# apache is not allwing me to use port number 443 in virtual tag for configuring apache for https service

Tags: php, apache, openssl, ssl-certificate

i am trying to configure apache for https service in xampp , i am almost done 
i am jsut struggling with that virtual tag in which i have give information about my self-signed ssl-certificate and key file , apache is not allowing me to use port number 443 in virtual tag even though i have no other service is running on this port , instead its working very well with any other free port like 55000

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
# Server Certificate:
SSLCertificateFile "C:/xampp/apache/bin/mycert.crt"
# Server Private Key 
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/xampp/apache/bin/mykey1.key"
SSLEngine On
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Do you have an error message?

Comment: yes sir "Error : apache shutdown unexpectedly , this may be due to a blcoked port, missing dependencies , improper privileges ......."

Comment: then check the error log. e.g. did you put in a `Listen` directive? You can't just stuff any port you want into a virtual directive...

Comment: oh yes i do change in listen directive and servername too , all the palces i have put the same port, listen 443 ,servername localhost:443

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.